# String path to base64string

Tags: c#, string, tobase64string

Im having a problem generating a base64string with a specific encoder.

I have an application that generate this base64string

```
RQA6AFwAUAByAG8AagBlAGMAdABzAFwAWQBvAHUAdAB1AGIAZQAuAE0AYQBuAGEAZwBlAHIAXABZAG8AdQB0AHUAYgBlAC4ATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAE0AbwBkAGUAbABzAC4AQwBvAG4AdABhAGkAbgBlAHIAXABvAGIAagBcAFIAZQBsAGUAYQBzAGUAXABuAGUAdABzAHQAYQBuAGQAYQByAGQAMgAuADAAXABZAG8AdQB0AHUAYgBlAC4ATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAE0AbwBkAGUAbABzAC4AQwBvAG4AdABhAGkAbgBlAHIALgBkAGwAbAAAAA==
```

which is equal to

```
E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\obj\Release\netstandard2.0\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll
```

Now im trying convert

```
E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\obj\Release\netstandard2.0\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll
```

To base64string but im getting this instead

```
RTpcUHJvamVjdHNcWW91dHViZS5NYW5hZ2VyXFlvdXR1YmUuTWFuYWdlci5Nb2RlbHMuQ29udGFpbmVyXG9ialxSZWxlYXNlXG5ldHN0YW5kYXJkMi4wXFlvdXR1YmUuTWFuYWdlci5Nb2RlbHMuQ29udGFpbmVyLmRsbA==
```

I want to get the same result as the first base64string which is

```
RQA6AFwAUAByAG8AagBlAGMAdABzAFwAWQBvAHUAdAB1AGIAZQAuAE0AYQBuAGEAZwBlAHIAXABZAG8AdQB0AHUAYgBlAC4ATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAE0AbwBkAGUAbABzAC4AQwBvAG4AdABhAGkAbgBlAHIAXABvAGIAagBcAFIAZQBsAGUAYQBzAGUAXABuAGUAdABzAHQAYQBuAGQAYQByAGQAMgAuADAAXABZAG8AdQB0AHUAYgBlAC4ATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAE0AbwBkAGUAbABzAC4AQwBvAG4AdABhAGkAbgBlAHIALgBkAGwAbAAAAA==
```

How can i do it?

This is my code which is giving me a wrong result

```
  var bytes= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: I bet the problem are the backslashes. Try a replace of them with a forward-slash. From the path perspective should be equivalent, after all.

Comment: Nope, test your suggesting here if you like https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8B8DwU This will be closer, i am not sure why the ends dont match though `AAAAA==` compared to `AA=`

Comment: FWIW The encoding for the first source string was UTF-16 (Little Endian)

Comment: @Alen.Toma then likely they've used a custom alphabet, instead the standard one.

Comment: @TheGeneral `AAAAA==` means it's nul-terminated.  Depending on the B64 string length (mod 3) you'll get one of the following for nul-terminated Unicode strings. `"AAAA", "AAAA=", "AAAAA=="`

Comment: @Corey yeah just read your post. i missed it by this much =>....<=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the text encoding you're using.

The first Base64 string you posted is encoded using Unicode with a nul terminator byte pair.  The trailing 'AAAAA==' is a dead giveaway here.  You can see it yourself by examining the byte array:

```
var originalB64 = "RQA6AFwAUAByAG8AagBlAGMAdABzAFwAWQBvAHUAdAB1AGIAZQAuAE0AYQBuAGEAZwBlAHIAXABZAG8AdQB0AHUAYgBlAC4ATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAE0AbwBkAGUAbABzAC4AQwBvAG4AdABhAGkAbgBlAHIAXABvAGIAagBcAFIAZQBsAGUAYQBzAGUAXABuAGUAdABzAHQAYQBuAGQAYQByAGQAMgAuADAAXABZAG8AdQB0AHUAYgBlAC4ATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAE0AbwBkAGUAbABzAC4AQwBvAG4AdABhAGkAbgBlAHIALgBkAGwAbAAAAA==";
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(originalB64);
```

Converting this to a string will give you a null-terminated string 125 characters long, with the last character being nul.

Given a path that is not nul-terminated you can reproduce that string as follows:

```
string path = @"E:\Projects\Youtube.Manager\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container\obj\Release\netstandard2.0\Youtube.Manager.Models.Container.dll";
string newB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(path + "\0"));
```

This matches the original Base64 string exactly in my tests.

Comment: @Alen.Toma I generally find it useful to look at the actual bytes when I can't see what's happening.  Especially when someone else is providing the data.

Comment: Yepp, i should read about base64string and understand it more.